# Rails Active job downloaded file not deleted by controller destroy action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activejob

I have just started learning rails and i am stuck at a problem:

I am developing a simple RoR app which has a text form and an image upload using active storage which on submit creates a (Post) and activates an active job which creates a MySql dump in the background and stores it to a directory.

My problem is that when i delete the (Post) everything is deleted except the generated dump.sql. So i want to be able to click on delete and delete everything associated with my Post including the dump. So i guess i have to somehow associate this new dump.sql file which has been generated in the background through an active job with my Post.

This is the controller create action where i call the active job on.

```
def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    if @post.save
        redirect_to home_path
        DumpSaveJob.perform_later
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

Here is the active job for generating the Dump in background:

```
class DumpSaveJob < ApplicationJob 
    queue_as :default

    def perform(*args)
        `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump -u root mypassword dump_app_development > storage/dumps/dump-$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S).sql` 
    end
end
```

Here the destroy controller action:

```
def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy
    redirect_to home_path
end
```

I expected rails to directly associate the active job dump file with my controller action/s specifically destroy, since the job is being called from the create action in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for anyone to know which posts and SQL dumps are related. First of all, I'm not sure if you really want to do a full dump of your entire DB when you create one new record, but if that's really the case this should do it:

1. pass the post object into your background job
2. create a text column in the posts table to store the filename of the associated SQL dump
3. after creating the dump, store the filename in the post
4. create an `after_destroy` hook in your post and enqueue a new job to delete the SQL dump file (pass the name into the job since your post won't exist anymore)

For that to work you probably also want to generate the filename in ruby, e.g. using the posts ID, so a) you can more easily store it in the post model and b) not have any issues when 2 posts get created at the same time.

The only time rails will know (and automatically remove files for you) is when you use `ActiveStorage` to store a file associated to a record. You could do this as well, especially if you want to store this file on an external storage such as S3. Note that this will not touch the original file that you are currently creating in `storage/dumps`.